# Integrity constraint violation in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have created table with Composite Primary Key, but while edit giving Integrity constraint violation error in cakephp.

> Integrity constraint violation : 1062 Duplicate entry while saving Composite Primary Key data of model

Answer (score 1):

Integrity constraint violations mean that you are trying to save a duplicate of a Unique value in the database. Primary Keys have to be Unique.

Do you have your Primary Key field in your database set to auto increment? If you do not, that may be your problem.

Otherwise, when you insert a record, it's probably going to insert a row with PK of 0. Then when it tries to insert another record, it will try to insert another row with PK of 0, thus not being unique, and throwing the Integrity Constraint violation.

**However**

You mentioned that you are doing an *edit*. If you are doing an edit, then you are not passing the edited rows Primary Key when you are saving it to the database, so cake tries to do a CREATE instead, thus resulting in another duplicate row ID.

Make sure you do this:

```
$this->Model->id = $id; // Where $id is the Primary Key of the row being edited.
```

Conversely, you can also do this:

```
$data['Model']['id'] = $id;
$this->Model->save($data);
```

You can capture the $id by either storing it as a hidden field in your edit form, or as a URL parameter passed to the action.